# 9 Errors Parse Facebook SDK

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

Help me please!

Errors

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o) ld: symbol(s)
>   not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: LOL I'm pretty sure that HTML didn't cause those linker errors....

Comment: Oh jeez.... please remove the giant images, and *copy and paste the relevant code into the question*. It should be properly-formatted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend including facebook SDK via CocoaPods. Facebook has very good explanation how to include SDK:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Link the Social and Accounts frameworks to your target.
[image]

Comment: ![show the image](http://triestebus.com/3.png).![show the image](http://triestebus.com/2.png).![show the image](http://triestebus.com/4.png).

Answer (score 0):

Remove ParseFacebookUtils.framework to fix it.